# How to write text output from nunit in a file?

Tags: .net, nunit, log4net

How can I easily capture the NUnit's output (errors, info, anything, really) and write it on files?
If I could save on multiple files, one for error, and so forth, it would be great.

I aware that I can make use of log4net and create a logging class, but my goal is to use the already great output control that NUnit has.

And I would want to minimize the code on the tests, keeping them as readable and simple as possible.
Are there any good practices or a roadmaps for that purpose?
Like make log4Net capture the output, perhaps?

Comment: Are you using NUnit 3.0, or a 2.x version? [This page](https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Text-Output-from-Tests) explains some options in NUnit 3.0. In 2.x versions, when using nunit-console you can specify an output file. See the Redirecting Output section on [this page](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.5) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a million. I am using the NUnit 3. I am gonna study your links.